# Variables that expire after used X time(s)

Tags: php, security

Is it possible to make a function that unsets a variable when it is used X time(s)?

I'm aware of `unset()` and how it works.
This would be handy for the security sake.

For example to automaticlly unset personal information that I obtained from a MySQL database, having 1000-2000 `unset()` in the code just looks so messy!

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: If this existed, it would probably cause subtle bugs where variables stop existing while you're trying to use them.

Comment: It's impossible to count a raw variable's usage. You're better off using a class and counting the number of times a getter is called.

Comment: Why would you need this? All data is cleared when a script exits anyways.

Comment: I just dont want anyone to get away with user information, so you can basicly call it an "extra" security feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question doesn't make perfectly sense here's a possibility to do it:

```
class ExpiredValue {
    private $data;
    private $access_counter;
    private $max_access;

    public function __construct($data, $max_access) {
        $this->max_access = $max_access;
        $this->__invoke($data);
    }

    public function __invoke($data = null) {
        if(func_num_args() == 0) {
            $this->access_counter++;
            if($this->access_counter > $this->max_access) {
                $this->data = null; // remove data from memory
            }
            return $this->data;
        } else if(func_num_args() == 1) {
            $this->access_counter = 0;
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
$value = new ExpiredValue("<data>", 3);
echo $value(); // "<data>"
$value("<other data>");
echo $value(); // "<other data>"
echo $value(); // "<other data>"
echo $value(); // "<other data>"
echo $value(); // null
```

Mostly if you begin to think about stuff like this you're on the wrong way. It sometimes helps to take a step back and figure out what the real problem is. Your problem is not really that there is not a good possibility to expire your variables.

Comment: I think the magic method `__get()` would be more appropriate here than `__invoke()`.

Comment: Its just an extra security to make sure, you never know if you maybe made a mistake somewhere and a potential hacker would get trough and then suddenly he sits with all information about users, mysql details etc.

Comment: @nickb why? I used `__invoke()` because it's shorter.

Comment: @OleKristianAanensen In this case forget about it. Better make sure the hacker doesn't get through. You only increase your effort unnecessary high without getting much security out of it.

Comment: Because it's counterintuitive - Without seeing the class definition, do you have any idea what `echo $value();` is doing? But, `echo $user->id;` is pretty obvious.